# End of file while reading data: Input/output error

Tags: libvirt

I use the below command to check the `libvirtd` status, but get error:

```
[root@ha-node1 nova]# systemctl status libvirtd.service 
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-08-03 00:09:05 CST; 25min ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 100447 (libvirtd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           └─100447 /usr/sbin/libvirtd --listen

Aug 03 00:09:05 ha-node1 libvirtd[100447]: libvirt version: 1.2.17, package: 13.el7 (CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>, 2015-11-20-16:24:10, worker1.bsys.centos.org)
Aug 03 00:09:05 ha-node1 libvirtd[100447]: Module /usr/lib64/libvirt/connection-driver/libvirt_driver_lxc.so not accessible
Aug 03 00:09:05 ha-node1 systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Aug 03 00:11:34 ha-node1 libvirtd[100447]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Aug 03 00:14:00 ha-node1 libvirtd[100447]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Aug 03 00:16:07 ha-node1 libvirtd[100447]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Aug 03 00:18:13 ha-node1 libvirtd[100447]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Aug 03 00:20:20 ha-node1 libvirtd[100447]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Aug 03 00:22:38 ha-node1 libvirtd[100447]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Aug 03 00:23:52 ha-node1 libvirtd[100447]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
```

The snapshot is below, you can see the error obviously.

Comment: I have the same problem - did you find any solution for that issue?